# Derive a relation between angles A,B and C

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

Derive a relation between angles A,B and C (do not use other angles in the final relation):
[image]

I have tried to use two theorems in triangles(external angle and complement angles),but no success! It seems my equations are not independent,and each time I get to obvious equalities such as: $90-A=90-A$. What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: I assume that what they're after is that $C = A + B$.

Comment: How did you get that relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what they're really after is that $C = A + B$, then it is proven, for instance, in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5evLoL0xwg), by Numberphile (note that what they prove there is that $A + B + C = 90^\circ$, but if you know that $C = 45^\circ$, then we also have $A + B = 45^\circ$, so $C = A+B$ follows).

The proof works by extending the figure and adding two more right triangles with angle $B$. One then easily sees that the angles $B$ and $C$ appear next to the angle $A$, forming a right angle, $A+B+C=90^\circ$

[image: sketch of proof]

Comment: Although according to the picture it seems $\angle{C}=45$ but this assumption restricts the problem.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi It doesn't _seem_ like $C = 45^\circ$, it is _true_, since it makes a right, isosceles triangle.

Comment: What if ∠C is not $45$ ? Then can we derive a general relation?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi If $C \neq 45^\circ$, or in other words, if the things that look like squares in the figure are not really squares, then I don't think there is a simple relation between them. At the very least, $C = A + B$ and $A + B + C = 90^\circ$ fails.